# FPDM - how to protect fields on injection

Tags: php, pdf

I use this code to inject data in a pdf template using FPDM library

but I can edit the fields with acrobat reader

how can I protect each fields

```
$pdf = new FPDM($pdfFileName);
$pdf->Load($fields, false); 
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output('I',$outputFile);
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

We found the answer : as we export from inDesign, there is a read only option

just check "Buttons and Forms" tab